# Trying to input numbers in text area but failed with error:list object has no attribute

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am new to Python. Trying to fill web forms using it. The web form has following HTML code

```
<table class=" l1 ">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="inputtext" type="text" name="q" >
</td>
...
```

I have tried it by

```
pass_code = driver.find_elements_by_name('q')
pass_code.click()
pass_code.send_keys("abcde")
```

I have imported webdriver from selenium. When the program is made to run it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Retarded /Desktop/fail.py", line 23, in <module>
    pass_code.send_keys("abcde")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you want "find_element_by_name", which would return one element, not "find_elements_by_name" that will return a list, I don't have selenium in this machine to test, can you try it?

Comment: Tried it. It didnt work.

Comment: what was the result/ error message? How many elements with the name "q" do exist in your html? See my answer for more infos.

Comment: Only one element exists.

Comment: and find_element_by_name didnt work. the error was


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Retarded /Desktop/fail.py", line 19, in <module>
    pass_code = driver.find_element_by_name('n')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 330, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)

I dont have have 330 line in my code.It is about 20-25 lines.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "pass_code = driver.find_element_by_name('q')" instead of "pass_code = driver.find_element_by_name('n')"?

Comment: Also the 330 line refers to the "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py" file, not your code, your code error happened in line 19

Comment: sorry, my bad. It is 'q ' not 'n'.

Comment: So is the error the same with 'q' still?, that is weird. Is the table inside an iframe?

Comment: Yes.The error persists . There is no iframe. The table is under division,<div class="              ">

Comment: Can you please try " pass_code = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']") ", and copy paste the error if it fails?

Comment: Finally. It worked. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Really? I was expecting it to fail and get more information from the error, jeje. Well c'est la vie

Comment: @NoelSegura please post your comment as an answer so OP can accept it so the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffC sure, but I still don't know why it works

Comment: @NoelSegura It's probably because there is more than one element on the page with name `q`? Your XPath specifies an `input` with name `q`.

Comment: @JeffC But OPs find_element_by_name failed, as I understand it if it found a non-input element named q then it would have failed in the send_keys command.  But anyway, without the full html we'll never know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your lookup is failing, use xpath instead of name

```
pass_code = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']") "
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one element with the name `q` then you should go for just `find_element_by_name()` instead of `find_elements_by_name()`.

The first gives back an element, the second a list (where you need to tell selenium with which element in the list you want to continue to work with)

So try this code:

```
pass_code = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
pass_code.click()
pass_code.send_keys("abcde")
```

It can still be, that this will not work, for example when there are several elements with the name `q`.

The above code would just grab the first one it finds and execute its commands on it. If this is the case you might be better of with finding you elements via **CSS** or **xpath**.

Answer (score 0):

This means the page have multiple elements named `q`, so the

```
pass_code = driver.find_elements_by_name('q')
```

`pass_code` is a list.

try to use another way to get the target input, or just find the index of it in the list, then use `send_keys` to fill in the input that you want.

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't get " to find index of it in the list" in your reply. Can you please elaborate. How to find the index and where to find.

Comment: @sanjaysaahu  maybe `pass_code[0].send_keys("abcde") ` sort of this which depends on the page structure